# A C code showing difference between static and dynamic allocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management

I want to write a C code to see the difference between static and dynamic allocation.

That's my idea but it doesn't work.

It simply initializes an array of size `10`, but assigns `100` elements instead of 10. I'll then initialize another array large enough hoping to replace the 90 elements that're not part of `array1[10]`, then I print out the `100` elements of `array1`.

```
int i;    
int array1[10];
int array2[10000];

for(i=0;i<100;i++)
   array1[i] = i;

for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
   array2[i] = i+1;

for(i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
     printf("%d \n",array1[i]);
  }
```

What I hope to get is garbage outside then first 10 elements when using static allocation, afterwards, I'll use malloc and realloc to ensure that the 100 elements would be there correctly. But unfortunately, it seems that the memory is large enough so that the rest of the 100 elements wouldn't be replaced!

I tried to run the code on linux and use "ulimit" to limit the memory size, but it didn't work either.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4):

`C`doesn't actually do any boundary checking with regards to arrays. It depends on the OS to ensure that you are accessing valid memory.

Accessing outside the array bounds is undefined behavior, from the [c99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section Annex J.2 J.2 Undefined behavior includes the follow point:

> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the
>   given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int
>   a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

In this example you are declaring a stack based array. Accessing out of bound will get memory from already allocated stack space. Currently undefined behavior is not in your favor as there is no Seg fault. Its programmer's responsibility to handle boundary conditions while writing code in C/C++.

Comment: I'd say the behaviour is _not_ in your favour. A crash followed by the developer fixing the code is the best possible outcome.

Comment: I know that, I'm not asking why it printed out the 90 elements correctly :D.... I'm just asking what can I do to show that stack allocated areas can be overwritten.

Comment: @AhmadNourELDeen Please have a look on [Smashing the Stack for fun and profit](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/phrack/P49-14).

Answer (score 1):

When you access `array1[10]` and higher index values, the program will just keep writing into adjacent memory locations even though they don't "belong" to your array.  At some point you might try to access a memory location that's forbidden, but as long as you're mucking with memory that the OS has given to your program, this will run.  The results will be unpredictable though.  It could happen that this will corrupt data that belongs to another variable in your program, for example.  It could also happen that the value that you wrote there will still be there when you go back to read it if no other variable has been "properly assigned" that memory location. (This seems to be what's happening in the specific case that you posted.)

All of that being said, I'm not clear at all how this relates to potential differences between static and dynamic memory allocation since you've only done static allocation in the program and you've deliberately introduced a bug.

Comment: "afterwards, I'll use malloc and realloc to ensure that the 100 elements would be there correctly."

Comment: @AhmadNourELDeen I saw the line that you've quoted here, but I could not understand it.  What type of malloc call would give you something aligned with the arrays that you showed in your example?  What do you think is going to happen when you call realloc?  This doesn't have any clear context in the example that you posted and it's hard to guess what you would have meant since what you've showed so far has a definite bug that has no specifically defined behavior in the standard.

Comment: simply I'll use malloc to reserve 40 bytes (4*10) then realloc with (4*100) bytes. I want to show that dynamic allocation gives you control of what you can allocate from memory. What if I don't know the size of the array but I'll get it from the user? I can simply assume a very large number using static allocation, but better would be using realloc. I hope you get it :)

Comment: @AhmadNourELDeen You've outlined the case for dynamic allocation.  No doubt that it's more flexible at runtime.  It's still not clear how you're comparing anything about static and dynamic allocation by writing past the end of the static array. If you call malloc, you could still write past the end of the array that you've dynamically allocated with basically the same pitfalls.  Calling realloc will resize the array, but it may move it to a completely different location, so you would then lose the values that you wrote past the end of the array. Finally, an int is not necessarily 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You *do* get garbage after the first 10 elements of `array1`. All of the data after element 9 should not be considered allocated by the stack and can be written over at any time. When the program prints the 100 elements of `array1`, you might see the remnants of either `for` loop because the two arrays are allocated next to each other and normally haven't been written over. If this were implemented in a larger program, other arrays might take up the space after these two example arrays.

Comment: That what I've already stated in the question :) ... what should I do to limit the memory size or even force the second array to be after the 10-allocated elements of array1?

Comment: Right now you have somewhat of a problem-in-search-of-a-question. When you are putting your pieces together, it is far better to make sure each of the small pieces are correct rather than start with a flawed foundation and then hunting for a solution. You statically declare your array of 10 element, then when `i = 10` your remaining data must go somewhere else. Generally, you would dynamically allocate 10, then when you reach 10, `realloc` twice that amount and keep going...

Comment: @AhmadNourELDeen You've already limited the array to 10 elements. You cannot control where in memory your data will be, nor would you ever need to. In a simplified sense, you can only claim random sections of memory, resulting in the prevention of it from being overwritten by other programs.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the memory size won't resolve your problem, because when you create your two arrays, the second one should be **right after** the first one in memory.

Your code should do what you think it will, and on my computer, it does.
Here's my output :

`0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 
11 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
...`

What OS are you running your code on ? (I'm on linux 64bit).

Anyway, as everybody told you, **DON'T EVER DO THIS IN A REAL PROGRAM.** Writing outside an array is an undefined behaviour and could lead your program to crash.

Comment: Yeah I know :) ... it's just for learning purpose and not a real program. But I'm using linux 64bit as well !! maybe it's random behavior... I'll try it again

Answer (score 0):

Writing out of bounds of an array will prove nothing and is not well-defined. Generally, there's nothing clever or interesting involved in invoking undefined behavior. The only thing you'll achieve by that is random crashes.

If you wish to know where a variable is allocated, you have to look at addresses. Here's one example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  int stack;
  static int data = 1;
  static int bss  = 0;
  int* heap = malloc(sizeof(*heap));

  printf("stack: %p\n", (void*)&stack);
  printf(".data: %p\n", (void*)&data);
  printf(".bss:  %p\n", (void*)&bss);
  printf(".heap: %p\n", (void*)heap);
}
```

This should print 4 distinctively different addresses (.data and .bss probably close to each other though). To know exactly where a certain memory area starts, you either need to check some linker script or use a system-specific API. And once you know the memory area's offset and size, you can determine if a variable is stored within one of the different memory segments.